# Java Custom Generic List: add() method error

Tags: java, generics

I have a task in which I have to implement an `add()` method for a custom generic list. In my code i have the following structure:

```
public abstract class MyGenericListAbstract<T> {
    protected transient T head;
    protected transient T tail;
    protected transient int size;

    ...
}

public final class MyEmptyList<T> extends MyGenericListAbstract {

private T[] list;

... 
public final void add(T e)
{
    this.getList()[this.size()] = (T) e;
}

...

private T[] getList()
{
    return this.list;
}
```

}

The problem I have for now is that when i try to do this:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGenericListAbstract <Integer> list0   = new MyEmptyList();
        list0.add(new Integer(3));
    }

}
```

I get the following error:

[image]

and I cannot figure out why ...

Can anyone please help me?

The entire code is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/mvlasceanu/custom-generic-list/src/66c8dd4464779a3e1d9ae767d2a2220ce628c686/src/dk/itu/oop/reexam/task3/?at=master), also some documentation about the task [here](https://bitbucket.org/mvlasceanu/custom-generic-list/src/66c8dd4464779a3e1d9ae767d2a2220ce628c686/doc/task3.doc?at=master#). If you spot some flaws, I would be happy to hear them!

Thanks!

Comment: Well, does `MyGenericListAbstract` have an `add` method?

Comment: This is unfortunate to start with: `public final class MyEmptyList<T> extends MyGenericListAbstract`. That's using the *raw* type `MyGenericListAbstract`. Try `public final class MyEmptyList<T> extends MyGenericListAbstract<T>`. Likewise you should probably use `MyGenericListAbstract <Integer> list0   = new MyEmptyList<>();`. Avoid raw types as far as possible.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis no, it doesn't

Comment: Why are you doing `(T) e;` whereas `e` is already a type of `T`?

Comment: @Braj NetBeans suggested it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hold a reference to `MyGenericListAbstract <Integer>` in `list0` whereas it doesn't have an `add` method, as you previously said in a comment. The compiler doesn't see that method based on the list reference.

You should either change the reference type to `MyEmptyList <Integer>` or move the `add(T e)` method to `MyGenericListAbstract` class.

PS. The problem is not related with generics, it's just the basic Java inheritance principle.